# Dialog isn't centered when keyboard appears

Tags: android, dialog

When keyboard becomes visible dialog isn't centered. It is custom dialog that **directly extends `Dialog` class**.

What I've tried to do:

- Set `adjustResize` in `AndroidManifest.xml` to acitivity that creates dialog
- `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)` in dialog
- Wrap my dialog with `DialogFragment` and show

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after struggling a lot I finally have found solution.

Create custom style

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden</item>
</style>
```

Apply this theme in constructor

```
public CustomDialog(Activity activity) {
    super(activity, R.style.DialogTheme);
    ...
}
```

Anything else simply doesn't work.